# Expression that refers to an event that appears in the news very fast?

Tags: expressions

The first thing that came to my mind was *an event like this would makes the headlines very quick*. But after checking on Google, I realized there were 0 results. So, obviously I was wrong.

What's the right expression for a case like this?

Comment: I'd also point out that strictly *quick* is an adjective - not an adverb - so you should say "makes the headlines very *quickly*".

Comment: I found one: *hit the headlines immediately* is that a common one?

Comment: *"scoop of the century"* [~40k hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=scoop+of+the+century&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22scoop+of+the+century%22&start=80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Viral news" or "has gone viral"

Many people refer to this as news that spreads very quickly on television, and especially on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Related terms include
• *[overnight sensation](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=overnight%20sensation)*, narrowly defined in urbandictionary with “When a certain unknown person becomes famous in a supposedly short amount of time, usually a day or a week”, but in general referring to anything suddenly newsworthy
• *[instant celebrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celebrity#Becoming_a_celebrity)*, “someone who becomes a celebrity in a very short period of time”
• *[flash in the pan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flash_in_the_pan)*, “A transient occurrence with no long-term effect”

Answer (score 1):

In the olden days (pre-Internet), one would say an event *stole the headlines* -- i.e., became immediately newsworthy. It has a decidedly old-school ring to it, but maybe it works for the Internet era, too.

Answer (score 0):

We can say that someone or something steals the limelight.

> Definition of [Limelight](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/limelight?s=t):
>
> The center of public attention, interest, observation, or notoriety.

Answer (score 0):

When something is used to describe a big event that is unexpected, the news channels usually say it is **breaking news**.

And I hate to throw a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=breaking%20news&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), but you can easily see that almost every major news organization has a breaking news page/section.